# oracle DBへのJDBCのcharsetについて

Tags: oracle, jdbc

Oracle DB(AL32UTF8)に対してJDBCで接続して、S-JISのテキストファイルをOracle DB(AL32UTF8)にあるテーブルに取り込もうとしているのですが、JDBCのCHARSETはどこでどのように機能しているのかがよくわかっておらず、JDBCのCHARSETはUTF-8にする必要があるのでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Oracleにはクライアント側が利用する環境変数にNLS_LANGがあります。
NLS_LANGはもともと３部構成になっていて、以下3の部分が文字コードに関わります
（NLS_LANG例）
JAPANESE_JAPAN.JA16SJISTILDE
1_______ 2____ 3____________

これは「Oracleサーバ側に、クライアント側の文字コードは××ですよ」と伝えるためのものです。
もし、サーバ側のキャラクターセットと、クライアント側プログラムが扱うキャラクターセットが異なる場合であっても、この環境変数にさえクライアント側の要求するキャラクターセットを指定しておけば
OracleNetサービスが自動で変換を行ってくれます。（クライアントアプリは意識する事ありません）
言い方を変えると、Oracleは内部の文字コードが何であっても、クライアント側の指定するNLS_LANGに合わせてやり取りしてくれるといえます。
今回のケースでは、Shift_JIS系のファイルをJavaで読み込みutf-8に変換するのであれば、
NLS_LANG環境変数へJapanese_Japan.AL32UTF8を設定しておけば問題ないと思います。